# Why is the weak self reference in the UIView animation closure causing a compilation error in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, weak-references

I'm getting a compile error when trying to use a weak reference in the UIView animation closure. Based upon other tutorials and Apple's documentation this should be valid.

**Snippet**

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0.35, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeCubicPaced, animations:{ [weak self] in

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0, animations:{

        if let actualSelf = self {
            actualSelf.noPlayListsView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.5, 1.5)
        }
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0, animations:{

        if let actualSelf = self {
            actualSelf.noPlayListsView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9)
        }
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0, animations:{

        if let actualSelf = self {
            actualSelf.noPlayListsView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }
    })
}, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 22):

You don't need to use [weak self] in static function UIView.animate() at all

Static (global) functions don't increment reference counter

[Apple closures docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

> Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures. Closures take one of three forms:
>
> Global functions are closures that have a name and do not capture any values.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was my keyframe animation was in the completion block of a parent animation so I need to move the reference, `[weak self]`, into that closure.

Everything now works as expected

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in

    if let actualSelf = self {
        actualSelf.noPlayListsView.alpha = 1.0
    }

    }, completion: { [weak self] finished in

        if (finished) {

            /// Key frame to let the user know
            /// weak: Have self automatically set to nil if it is deallocated

            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 0.5, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeCubicPaced, animations:{

                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0, animations:{

                    if let actualSelf = self {
                        actualSelf.noPlayListsView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
                    }
                })

                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0, animations:{

                    if let actualSelf = self {
                        actualSelf.noPlayListsView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
                    }
                })

                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0, animations:{

                    if let actualSelf = self {
                        actualSelf.noPlayListsView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                    }
                })
            }, completion:nil)
        }
})
```